# How to create App Folder programmatically?

Tags: android, android-launcher

I want to create App Folder when one app come over another app on Home Screen / App Drawer  (As Default Android System/Launcher Provides).

I searched lot for this but it only shows either LiveFolder or shows how we can use it (Using System Default feature). How do I implement this programmatically?

Comment: Create custom android OS!

Comment: You mean android Launcher ?